# How to get list information along with number of list items stored in another table using active records?

Tags: sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have a table `lists` containing list information like `title` and `id` (auto_increment) and another table storing items. The `list_items` table has a `parent` field which is the id of the list it belongs to.

I'm trying to pull list information with an additional column for keeping track of number of items for that list stored under `list_items`.

This query works:

`select lists.*, x.cnt
from lists, (select count(*) as cnt from list_items) as x`

How to write the same using CodeIgniter Active Record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
$this->db->select('lists.*, x.cnt from lists, (select count(*) as cnt from list_items) as x', NULL, FALSE);
$result = $this->db->get('Table_Name');
```